# How do I get a sidekiq retry job from re-appearing in the dashboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

It seems like I have a job that is failing, but when it fails it still persists and then creates another identical job like itself.  Notice in my screenshot that the top item and the bottom item are the same ,arguments '836898'.  Is this some kind of configuration that i need to change?

I am referring to the duplicate entries showing up, not necessarily disabling retries.

[image: Arguments 836898 failing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two entries in the Retries because they are two different jobs.  You can create "identical" jobs (with the same class and arguments) that differ only in their internal Job ID.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first include `gem 'sidekiq-unique-jobs'`

Then your worker should look like this

```
class CleanupWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :cleanup, unique: :until_executed, retry: 4, failures: :exhausted, backtrace: true

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    10 * (count + 1)
  end

  def perform(args)
  end
end
```

`unique: :until_executed` this means the job must be unique as long as it is still in the queue or it is being executed. the combination between the `retries: 4` and `unique: :until_executed` will do the trick. Because as far as I know when the job crash if the retries is not false then the job will get back to the queue.

here is the [link](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs) for this unique job gem repo

Answer (score 0):

NickM's answer is right. However, it will disable retries for all sidekiq workers. Depending on each case, I recommend to disable it in each class like:

```
class NonRetryableWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform
  end
end
```

Or perhaps, just limit the number of retries like:

```
class LessRetryableWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 5

  def perform
  end
end
```

You can check more info [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration)

Comment: I dont want to disable retries, I'm wondering why there are duplicate entries in my retries table?

Comment: Hum... but if it fails, it will retry that same job and trigger a new one. Aren't we talking about the same thing? Sorry if I'm understanding it